# Are the two definitions of the complementary Young function equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

**The description of the problem:**

For a Young function I would refer the reader to the book "Function spaces" by Pick Luboš, Kufner Alois, John Oldrich and Fucík Svatopluk, and published by de Gruyter. The following **Definition 1** is about the complementary Young function which would be found in this book (see p.115).

**Definition 1**. Let $\Phi $ be a Young function generated by a function $\varphi$, that is, 
$$
\Phi(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\varphi(s)ds, \ t \in \left [ 0, \infty\right ).
$$
We set 
$$\psi(t)=\underset{\varphi(s)\leq t}{ \sup}s$$

and 
$$
\Psi(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\psi(s)ds, \ t\in \left [0,\infty  \right ).
$$
The function $\Psi$ is called the complementary function to $\Phi$.

However, I have found another kind of definition of $\Psi$ in many occasions. See below:

**Definition 2**. Geven a Young function $\Phi$, the complementary Young function $\Psi$ is defined by 
$$
\Psi(t)=\underset{s>0}{\sup}\left \{ st-\Phi(s) \right \}, \ t>0.
$$

---

**My question is:**

Are these two definitions equivalent? And if they are, how can we proof this result?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two definitions are equivalent. If the functions are smooth (and I am not aware of any reason to use nonsmooth Young functions), verification is easy: in the second definition, the supremum defining $\Psi$ is attained when $t=\Phi'(s)$. Write $\phi=\Phi'$ and $\psi=\phi^{-1}$, so that  $s=\psi(t)$. Then
$$\Psi(t) = \sup_{s>0} (st-\Phi(s))= t\psi(t)-\Phi(\psi(t))$$
which implies
$$\Psi'(t) =  t\psi'(t)+\psi(t)-\phi(\psi(t))\psi'(t) = \psi(t) $$
which conforms to the first definition of $\Psi$.

For general functions, the fact that the definitions agree is the content of [Young's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions) 
$$ab \le \left(\int_0^a \phi\right)+\left( \int_0^b \psi\right)$$
(where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other). The inequality has a nice "proof by a picture", which I took from Wikipedia:

[image: Young's inequality]

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer! Since the $\phi$ and $\psi$ are not assumed to be strictly increasing, we may not have the equation $\phi^{-1}=\psi$ for every point in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. But I think it would not be an obstacle. Indeed, the Young's inequality would be more intrinsic.

Comment: The Young's inequality shoud be of the form: $ab\leq \left (\int^{a}_{0}\phi \right ) +\left ( \int^{b}_{0} \psi \right )$

Comment: @WangtFei Correct, in general we don't have invertibility. But the proof by picture stays the same: draw the graph of $\phi$ and look at its sideways to see the graph of $\psi$. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes, I have grasped the thread in your proof just by the picture that you have mentioned here. But it would still cost some other  time if we treat it more strictly. Hence, seeing from a picture may be a choice of a nice "proof".

Answer (score 0):

The is YES if $\varphi$ is invertible. In this case, we clearly have
$$\psi= \varphi^{-1}.$$

The second definition
$$\Psi(t)= \sup_{s>0} [st-\Phi(s)]= at-\varphi(a) \quad\text{for some }a>0$$

Note that $a$ exists by convexity and we have $\Psi(0)=0$. Since $\Phi'=\varphi$ even have

$$\frac{d}{ds}[st-\Phi(s)](a)=0\Longleftrightarrow t=\varphi(a)\Longleftrightarrow a=\varphi^{-1}(t)$$

which means that $$\Psi(t) = at-\varphi(a)= t\varphi^{-1}(t)-\Phi(\varphi^{-1}(t))$$

That is we have $$\Psi'(t) =  t(\varphi^{-1})'(t)+\varphi^{-1}(t)-(\varphi^{-1})'(t)\Phi'(\varphi^{-1}(t))= t(\varphi^{-1})'(t)+\varphi^{-1}(t)-(\varphi^{-1})'(t)\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(t))= \varphi^{-1}(t). $$

This shows that
$$\Psi(t)=\sup_{s>0} [st-\Phi(s)]= \Psi(0)+\int_0^t \Psi'(s) ds=\int_0^t \varphi^{-1}(s) ds=\int_0^t \psi(s) ds.$$